# Do enzymes that digest ᴅ-glucose react with ʟ-glucose?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, isomers, carbohydrates, enzymes

ᴅ-Glucose is common in nature and ʟ-glucose is synthesized in the lab.

I know that humans can't use ʟ-glucose in their aerobic pathways because it doesn't match the active site of the enzyme, but why can't our cells use ʟ-glucose?

Comment: You can't put a left shoe on your right foot. Same thing here. Enzymes are chiral too.

Comment: Alice speaking to Kitty. ‘How would you like to live in Looking-glass House, Kitty? I wonder if they’d give you milk in there? Perhaps Looking-glass milk isn’t good to drink—' I have always felt that Lewis Carroll was aware of the mirror image world. Is milk (lactose) on the other side comprised of L-glucose and L-galactose? Is that why Alice questions whether it is good to drink? @Ivan Neretin

Comment: Wikipedia has a pretty good answer; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-Glucose. It includes one species able to digest L-Glucose, and the information that the taste is the same (which makes you wonder about those chiral taste receptors).